# Trying to create a simple while loop using Rbutton VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, while-loop

**Not important:**
I started learning VB.Net yesterday, I'm learning basic functions that I use in other languages, but I don't find much direct content about VB.Net

**The real question:**
I have no idea how i can use while RButton down loop something... ill send what i need to loop, if someone can help me...

**Edit:** I found another problem, i can send the keys in game chatbox, but the real function of the keys isnt working)

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    KEYB_Event(VK_KEY_Q, 0, 0, 0)
    KEYB_Event(VK_KEY_Q, 0, 0, 0)
    KEYB_Event(VK_KEY_Q, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
    Thread.Sleep(5)

    KEYB_Event(VK_KEY_W, 0, 0, 0)
    KEYB_Event(VK_KEY_W, 0, 0, 0)
    KEYB_Event(VK_KEY_W, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
    Thread.Sleep(5)

    KEYB_Event(VK_KEY_E, 0, 0, 0)
    KEYB_Event(VK_KEY_E, 0, 0, 0)
    KEYB_Event(VK_KEY_E, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
    Thread.Sleep(5)

    KEYB_Event(VK_KEY_E, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: A While loop inside of a timer is just begging for problems. Can you explain what it is that you're actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: *"I found another problem"*. Then post another question about that. SO questions need to be specific. You don't ask multiple questions in one thread.

Comment: You wouldn't use a `While` loop at all. Your form has `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events. Handle them. `Start` your `Timer` on the former and `Stop` it on the latter. Your `Timer` will now `Tick` continually in between.

Comment: @David
Its a auto-potion system for ''Mu online'' games. You need to spamm Q,W,E fastest than you can to use life potions while you are on pvp mode. The Rbutton use skills, so... Im trying to use potions while im using skills